# currently working on 3.4 cakephp frame work .i get an issue on request action

Tags: cakephp

An Internal Error Has Occurred
Error: Controller actions can only return Cake\Network\Response or null.

please suggest to me resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

The error says what you have to Do. Just try:

```
return $this->response->send();
```